# Как правильно перебрать данный массив

Tags: php

С сервера приходит вот такой массив:

```
  Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
     [date_of_monitoring] => Array ( 
       [0] => dsd
       [14] => фывафы )
     [manager] => Array (
       [1] => ass
       [15] => павыпфыап ) 
     [work_info] => Array (
       [2] => fdf 
       [16] => апроап ) 
     [news] => Array ( 
       [3] => gbb 
       [17] => ывап ) 
    ) 
  )
```

Нужно вставить его значения в таблицу, по полям

```
   <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>[date_of_monitoring]</td> 
            <td>[manager]</td> 
            <td>[work_info]</td> 
            <td>[news]</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Как-то так, через цикл, чтобы значения выводились все, что есть в таблице. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: <?php
$arr(Ваш массив);
$chery=count($arr);

for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) {


 echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
  echo'<tr>';

  echo '<td style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.serialize($arr[$i]['date_of_monitoring']).'<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['manager']).'<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($da2[$i]['work_info']).'<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($da2[$i]['news']).'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
echo'</table>';

}

?>

Comment: Тут вложенный массив, по этому применил .serialize который просто позволит в ячейках увидеть данные json_encode

Comment: Получилось?....

Comment: да, спасибо большое!

Comment: тогда ответом оформлю, ставль лайк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <?php $arr(Ваш массив); 
        $chery=count($arr); 
        for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) { 
        echo'<table cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">'; 
    echo'<tr>'; 
echo '<td style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.serialize($arr[$i]['date_of_monitoring']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['manager']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['work_info']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['news']).'</td>';
         echo'</tr>';
         echo'</table>'; 
        } 
        ?>
```